# login and registration program getting an error nullpointerxeption

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hello I'm trying to develop a login and registration program using php and mysql. I'm using phpmyadmin and the URL is localhost android_login..

When I run the program I'm getting a exception that is like this

08-21 15:30:07.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 15:30:07.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9712): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 15:30:07.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9712):     at com.example.ritkigatestadatabas.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:65)
08-21 15:30:07.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9712):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
08-21 15:30:07.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9712):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)

```
THIS IS THE RegisterActivity

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
        Button btnRegister;
        Button btnLinkToLogin;
        EditText inputFullName;
        EditText inputEmail;
        EditText inputPassword;
        TextView registerErrorMsg;

        // JSON Response node names
        private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
        private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
        private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
        private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
        private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
        private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.register);

            // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
            inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
            btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
            btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
            registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

            // Register Button Click event
            btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                    Log.i("funkar","skickar" + name);
                    JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);
                    Log.i("funkar","får tillbaka json");


                    // check for login response
                    try {
                        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                            if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                                // user successfully registred
                                // Store user details in SQLite Database
                                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                                JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                                // Clear all previous data in database
                                userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                                db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                       
                                // Launch Dashboard Screen
                                Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                                // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                                dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(dashboard);
                                // Close Registration Screen
                                finish();
                            }else{
                                // Error in registration
                                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            // Link to Login Screen
            btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    // Close Registration View
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

THIS IS THE USER FUNCTIONS CLASS

```
public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;

    // Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp

    private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/ah_login/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/ah_login/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    //public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }

}
```

THIS IS THE JSON parser

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);           
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}


Here is the RegisterActivity Class

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
        Button btnRegister;
        Button btnLinkToLogin;
        EditText inputFullName;
        EditText inputEmail;
        EditText inputPassword;
        TextView registerErrorMsg;

        // JSON Response node names
        private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
        private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
        private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
        private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
        private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
        private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.register);

            // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
            inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
            btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
            btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
            registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

            // Register Button Click event
            btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                    Log.i("funkar","skickar" + name);
                    JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);
                    Log.i("funkar","får tillbaka json");


                    // check for login response
                    try {
                        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                            if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                                // user successfully registred
                                // Store user details in SQLite Database
                                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                                JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                                // Clear all previous data in database
                                userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                                db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                       
                                // Launch Dashboard Screen
                                Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                                // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                                dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(dashboard);
                                // Close Registration Screen
                                finish();
                            }else{
                                // Error in registration
                                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            // Link to Login Screen
            btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    // Close Registration View
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Can somebody pls help me. Thank you

Comment: use my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem, based on a quick google search, that since Honeycomb you are not supposed to execute network access on your app's main thread (to improve responsiveness).

Create another thread for network access

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

use this code in your code where your calling network related thread/code

copy paste below code in your userFunctions.java file

```
public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;

    // Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp

    private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/ah_login/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/ah_login/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    //public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Aleksander use my edited answer

Comment: yeeeees :) thank you that solved the error, but now i get one more exeption that is like this------ 08-21 15:30:07.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 15:30:07.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9712): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 15:30:07.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9712):  at com.example.ritkigatestadatabas.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:65)
08-21 15:30:07.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9712):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
08-21 15:30:07.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9712):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)

Comment: am not getting you you have one more issue?

Comment: as per logcat .error is in RegisterActivity please show your code of .RegisterActivity in your question please edit your question with code of .RegisterActivity

Comment: is everything to me can you hel n me with the nullpointerexeption

Comment: Mr Downvoter can you show your face and will tell you why you downvote ? this is working solution

Comment: @Aleksander  as per logcat .error is in RegisterActivity please show your code of .RegisterActivity in your question please edit your question with code of .RegisterActivity

Answer (score 0):

yesterday i have same problem, you can use allowing permission
 `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);`

But better you use `AsyncTask` for long background process. Just for suggestion to improve

Comment: why downvote?? i think its better suggestion